# Chain of comparators in java

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

Reading the [Java Tutorial by Oracle on interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) which gives a example on `Card` (Playing cards) I was trying to understand the [default methods in interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html). Here's the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html), section "Integrating default methods in existing interfaces". Now in the last section they sorted the Cards first by rank and then by suits. Following logics have been given. Assume that whatever interfaces, functions or classes that are used have been defined and `sort` function takes a `Comparator`

Logic 1:

```
package defaultmethods;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class SortByRankThenSuit implements Comparator<Card> {
    public int compare(Card firstCard, Card secondCard) {
        int compVal =
            firstCard.getRank().value() - secondCard.getRank().value();
        if (compVal != 0)
            return compVal;
        else
            return firstCard.getSuit().value() - secondCard.getSuit().value(); 
    }
}
```

Logic 2:

```
myDeck.sort(
    Comparator
        .comparing(Card::getRank)
        .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Card::getSuit)));
```

Now I am having some problems in understanding the second logic. I read the comparator interfaces and the new static methods which have been included in Java 1.8 . Now I understand something like this `myDeck.sort(Comparator.comparing(Card::getRank))` which sorts by rank but after reading [the documentation for `thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-) , I am unable to understand how `thenComparing` returns a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which achieves the above Logic 1. Does it internally build something like the `if-else` construct as specified in Logic 1 ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, it creates internally something similar, just with more intermediate lambdas. Assuming that your `getRank` and `getSuit` methods return some instances of comparable classes `Rank` and `Suit`, in your case you effectively have:

```
Function<Card, Rank> toRank = Card::getRank;
Comparator<Card> comp1 = (a, b) -> toRank.apply(a).compareTo(toRank.apply(b));
Function<Card, Suit> toSuit = Card::getSuit;
Comparator<Card> comp2 = (a, b) -> toSuit.apply(a).compareTo(toSuit.apply(b));
Comparator<Card> result = (a, b) -> {
  int res = comp1.compare(a, b);
  return res != 0 ? res : comp2.compare(a, b);
};
```

So after inlining (which might be performed by JIT-compiler) you may have something like this:

```
Comparator<Card> result = (a, b) -> {
  int res = a.getRank().compareTo(b.getRank());
  return res != 0 ? res : a.getSuit().compareTo(b.getSuit());
};
```

Note that you can use the simpler version:

```
myDeck.sort(
    Comparator
        .comparing(Card::getRank)
        .thenComparing(Card::getSuit));
```

Answer (score 12):

This is the implementation on my machine (Oracle JDK 8u40)

```
default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Comparator<? super T> other) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(other);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable) (c1, c2) -> {
        int res = compare(c1, c2);
        return (res != 0) ? res : other.compare(c1, c2);
    };
}
```

so yes, it is essentially if else (more precisely, the ternary operator).

Comment: My IDE (IntelliJ) pulls it in for me.  On my mac it is in: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/src.zip!/java/util/Comparator.java

Comment: @AbKDs, in src.zip file inside your JDK installation. Or [online](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Comparator.java#Comparator.thenComparing%28java.util.Comparator%29).

Comment: @AbKDs FYI, in 2017-09 [Oracle announced](http://www.zdnet.com/article/oracle-proposes-production-distribution-changes-to-java-se/) that updates to Java 9 will bring the Oracle JDK closer and closer to being virtually identical with the OpenJDK project. So for source code, just look to the [OpenJDK project](http://openjdk.java.net) and its [Mercurial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) revision-control system.