# Sort an ArrayList by subclasses in Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

so I am trying to sort an ArrayList as the title says. I have A Superclass called `Thing` that has 2 different subclasses, a `HeavyThing` and a `LightThing`. The ArrayList contains just the 2 subclasses and I need to sort it so the `HeavyThing` comes before the `LightThing`.
So far I got the sort method to work for the name of the Things but I was unable to sort it by subclass.

```
        this.collThings.sort(new Comparator<Thing>() {
            public int compare(Thing t1, Thing t2) {
                return Integer.valueOf(t1.getName().compareTo(t2.getName()));
            }
        });
```

This is how I sorted it by name.

Answer (score 2):

You can create [a comparator chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32195321/1602555) and then as a first step compare [the class' simple name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName()). This will put `HeavyThing` before `LightThing` because in lexicographic order `H` comes before `L`. Then you can sub-sort by name:

```
this.collThings
    .sort(Comparator.comparing(t -> t.getClass().getSimpleName())
                    .thenComparing(Thing::getName));
```

Comment: Thank you this very useful, but I later down the line I have to sort the things by Date, Price etc. and I need to Sort the ArrayList just by telling if it is a heavy or a light thing.